# Creating a view that excludes entity referenced nodes

Tags: views, entities, users

Say I have a Content type of Fruit. I have an Entity Reference on the User Profile to Fruit nodes. I want to create a view that shows all Fruit nodes that are NOT referenced by the Entity Reference on the current user profile.

(More details: I can create a view that *includes* Fruit nodes on the current user profile, by creating a view of Fruit nodes with a Relationship to the Entity Reference on the User Profile. Alternatively, by creating a View of users, filtering by current users, and then using the entity reference to show the data from the Fruit nodes. However, I haven't found a way to create a view of Fruit nodes that are NOT referenced on the current User Profile.

Answer (score 0):

[Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) might help you:

> This module provides the feature missing in Views module - subquery filter for IN (NOT IN) condition, such as (quite informal):
>
> SELECT n.title FROM node n WHERE n.nid [IN | NOT IN] (SELECT n2.nid FROM node n2 WHERE ...)
>
> or
>
> SELECT n.title FROM node n WHERE n.node_reference_field [IN | NOT IN] (SELECT n2.nid FROM node n2 WHERE ...)

Comment: Thanks, I've not come across that before. I'll look into it.